# Custom Entity is only showing via admin theme

Tags: theming, entities

I implemented a custom content entity with Drupal console. By default the routing is done in JobListingEntityHtmlRouteProvider.php file. I am getting a standard path such as /admin/structure/my_custom_entity/id.

I tried to use URL alias pattern to change it such as /my_custom_entity/id. That worked but still give me the admin theme upon viewing the entity. I did defined a themable custom twig template but it's not picking it up.

I also changed _admin_route to FALSE in JobListingEntityHtmlRouteProvider.php routing file. No go.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did u flush the cache after changing it to false?

Comment: Yes I did. No change. Yet I don't see explicitly a entity "view" route for my entity defined. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Unlikely, can the route still be accessed via `/admin/structure/my_custom_entity/id` ?

Comment: Yes, they can still be accessed that way.

Comment: Did the Drupal Console generate a your_module.routing.yml file?

Comment: It did not. It generates a JobListingEntityHtmlRouteProvider.php file. It's a issue in Drupal Console as far as I can tell (I have latest version).

Comment: Don't use an alias, change the canonical path directly in the entity annotations, which probably now looks like: `"canonical" = "/admin/structure/my_custom_entity/{my_custom_entity}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 4k4 said in the comments, the route is being generated using the link template in the entity annotations. Changing these link templates should be how you set the path to any custom entity page. For future content entities, drupal console will use the base path specified in this step:
`Enter the base-path for the content entity routes [/admin/structure]`